# incorrect image coordinates when click image

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am using bygame and loading buttons as images on my scene, when I am trying to use `button[0].get_rect()` I receive coordinates 0,0 when click instead of the actual coordinates of the button.

my code as below

```
button = []
button.append(pygame.image.load('images/new_game.png').convert_alpha())
button_pos = (700, 100)
```

and inside the `while` used this code to check if the button is clicked

```
 screen.fill(0)
 screen.blit(button[0], button_pos)
 if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            x, y = event.pos
            if button[0].get_rect().collidepoint(x, y):
                scene = 2
                print(scene)
```

Comment: An surface does not know where it has been painted (could be multiple places), you need to track this yourself. Perhaps see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42577197/pygame-how-to-correctly-use-get-rect

Comment: I added a new variable including the coordinates and size for the image and it works, but in case that is a dynamic image position I'll not be able to control it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `button.get_rect()` is returning a Rect that describes the location and dimensions of the image as if it was positioned at (0,0).  It needs to be told where the right location co-ordinates are.

The code already has `button_pos`, so by just applying this to the Rect from `button[0].get_rect()` we get a final Rect with the correct position *and* dimensions.  It's then possible to check for collisions between this Rect and the event-supplied mouse position.

```
button_rect = button[0].get_rect()
button_rect.topleft = button_pos       # now the rect matches the on-screen 

# ...

screen.fill( 0 )
screen.blit( button[0], button_rect ) 

if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    x, y = event.pos
    if button_rect.collidepoint( x, y ):
        scene = 2
        print( scene )
```

Probably you want to make a list of button Rects and have one for each of the `button` list's images, but this example is based on what you've presented in the question, so doesn't do that.